# Get cURL to follow redirects

Tags: php, curl, http-redirect

I have an application in Laravel that scrapes sites and retrieves specific information.
Lately I've been seeing more and more sites getting 403 forbiidden so i decided to try cURL out for the first time.

The only problem i have now, is that sites that have 301 or 302 redirects, cURL doesn't follow them.

This is what I have:

```
$curl = curl_init(); 
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $results['url_search']);  
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);  
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 10);  
        curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_USERAGENT,'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.1.13) Gecko/20080311 Firefox/2.0.0.13');

        $str = curl_exec($curl);  

        $header_size = curl_getinfo($curl, CURLINFO_HEADER_SIZE);
        $header = curl_getinfo($curl, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
        $body = substr($str, $header_size);

        curl_close($curl);
```

So as I said, on pages where there are redirects, I get stuck. Any suggestions?
I've seen some things but none of them worked.

Comment: You can parse the headers, and make another curl request.

Comment: But how do i get the actual header response? What i have ($header = curl_getinfo($curl, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);) just gives me the number after being parsed. Can i use get_headers somehow?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`curl` has an option to achieve exactly what you are looking for,
following redirects:

```
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
```

Just add this line to your curl-options before your execution of it.

As you might expect, this will follow any 301 / 302 redirects and ends up on a site, which doesn't redirect your request any further.

Also, remember that (without having a workaround) this might lead to an infinite loop. (site a redirects to b and b redirects to a).

That said, you should use this option as well:

```
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS, 10);
```

This way, your requests will end after 10 redirects and you don't have to bother with your script running in an endless-loop.

A good source for your further work with diffrent options is the regarding site on [php.net](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php)

Comment: Thanks @DasSaffe this is exactly what i was looking for and it worked like a charm!