# How to get access token Strava Api with PHP

Tags: php, strava

```
public function auth_callback()
{
  if ($this->input->get("code") != null)
  {
    $this->Strava_model->UpdateProfileStravaToken($this->input->get("code"),$this->session->userdata("athlete_id"));
    $url = "http://www.strava.com/oauth/token?client_id=[xxxxx]&client_secret=[xxxxxxxxxxx]&code=".$this->input->get("code")."&grant_type=authorization_code";
            
    $post = array();
    $options = array(
        'http' => array(
        'header'  => "Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n",
        'method'  => 'POST',
        'content' => http_build_query($post)
        )
    );
    $context  = stream_context_create($options);
    $result = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);
    if ($result === FALSE) { /* Handle error */ }

        var_dump($result);
        echo $result;exit;
            
        $cURLConnection = curl_init($url);
        curl_setopt($cURLConnection, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post);
        curl_setopt($cURLConnection, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

        $apiResponse = curl_exec($cURLConnection);
        curl_close($cURLConnection);
        $jsonArrayResponse = json_decode($apiResponse);
            
        redirect($this->config->item("base_url") . "/activity");
  }
}
```

I manage to get the code, and now proceed to get access token.

I'm using php curl to send post as below:

> [http://www.strava.com/oauth/token?client_id=[xxxx]&client_secret=[xxxxx]&code=[code](http://www.strava.com/oauth/token?client_id=%5Bxxxx%5D&client_secret=%5Bxxxxx%5D&code=%5Bcode) retrieve from redirection]&grant_type=authorization_code

Once I executed the code above, I got this "You're being redirect..."

Can anyone advice and help?

Comment: Can you show your code for the CURL part, it may be a simple fix but at the moment it's just guesswork.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32522541/get-curl-to-follow-redirects.

Comment: Please add the code as well for us to look into.

Answer (score 0):

Generally requests to the OAuth2 token endpoint require parameters to be passed as form-data, in the request body. Based on your current source, you are sending an empty request body.

Comment: you mean the client_id, client_secret, code and also grant_type ??

Comment: I would look up OAuth2 documentation and figure out from there what your body should look like